# Display another view when tapping on Annotation

Tags: swift, swiftui, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have created a UIViewRepresantable to display a map in SwiftUI. I want display an overlay displaying information about the annotation to the map, once the annotation is tapped. Inside the Coordinator I am trying to use the didSelect method. Right now I am just trying to print "Tapped". But it just doesnt show anything. Anyone know what I might be missing?

My Code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
    var control: MapViews
    
    init(_ control: MapViews){
        self.control = control
        
    }
    
    
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            // 1
            guard annotation is LandmarkAnnotation else { return nil }
            // 2
            let identifier = "id"
            
            // 3
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
            
            if annotationView == nil {
                //4
                annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
                
                // 5
                let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
                
            } else {
                // 6
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            }
            
            return annotationView
            
        }
    
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print("Tapped")
    }
    }


struct MapViews: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    let landmarks: [Landmark]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  MKMapView {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        return map
    }
    
   func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext <MapViews>) {
        updateAnnotations(from: uiView)
    }
    
   func updateAnnotations(from mapView: MKMapView){
       let annotations = self.landmarks.map(LandmarkAnnotation.init)
       mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
       
    }
}
```

I tried to tap the annotation, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong instance method. Try [calloutAccessoryControlTapped](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1616211-mapview) like this:

```
func mapView(
  _ mapView: MKMapView,
  annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
  calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl
) { }
```